# SketchFlow prototyping font not displaying

Tags: silverlight-3.0, prototype, expression-blend, prototyping, sketchflow

I'm using SketchFlow for the first time, and am confused as to why my text isn't showing up in the "Buxton Sketch" font it's supposed to (see image). I just did a repair installation, and it didn't make a difference. In the Text properties, I don't see "Buxton Sketch" as an option, either. I'd appreciate any help.

**UPDATE**
Everything looks fine in the SketchFlow player (when I hit F5), but not in the designer.

[image: My messed-up SketchFlow font]

Compared to this:

[Proper "wiggly" font http://www.lorenheiny.com/wp-content/uploads/sketchflowwigglystyles.png](http://www.lorenheiny.com/wp-content/uploads/sketchflowwigglystyles.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried downloading the SketchFlow files from a [tutorial](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/ee426886.aspx) I had used, and it worked fine. It turned out the difference was that my files resided within a subfolder of a directory I had named "C#" - where I've kept all of my Visual Studio source files for a long time, with no problems (until now). Moving the SketchFlow project to a different directory fixed it.

What makes it even stranger is that the C# directory is 2 levels higher up than the solution's directory, so I don't know why anything within the solution would even matter.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to create anything with that font?  Can you create a textblock and set the text to the Buxton Sketch font?

Comment: No, nothing shows up with the Buxton font, and I don't see it available as a choice. When I place a "TextBlock-Sketch" on the canvas, its font property is set to "/<ProjectName>/<ProjectName>/<ProjectName>Screens/Fonts/BuxtonSketch.ttf#Buxton Sketch"

Comment: Also, do you have Buxton available in Word (or another text editor)? I don't.

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious, is the ttf file where it is specified by the xaml?  ("/<ProjectName>/<ProjectName>/<ProjectName>Screens/Fonts/BuxtonSketch.ttf#Buxton Sketch")

Comment: The sketch fonts with SketchFlow are not installed system wide, if you want to do so, you could find them here: $(Program Files)\Microsoft Expression\Blend 3\ProjectTemplates\en\CSharp\WPF\SketchFlow\ControlLibrary  to install them just right click and pick install.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered this same issue - but found a slightly different solution.

In our case, SketchFlow projects were being in the default location (My Documents\Expression\Blend 3\Projects), and the screens weren't coming up with Buxton Sketch.

The difference we found is that, in our environment, "My Documents" is mapped to a network storage location (H:\Data). What we observed was:

- Open the project via My Documents\Expression\Blend 3\Projects. No Buxton Sketch. :-(
- Open the project via H:\Data\Expression Blend 3\Projects. Buxton Sketch OK. :-)

Comment: So it basically seems like they're using some kind of non-standard directory parsing that breaks on the file system's edge cases. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Click "Embed" in the Text properties on most "Sketchy" controls to get Buxton Sketch to appear at design time in Blend for MS Visual Studio 2013 (v 12.0.50429.0 update 2)

If you paste items from other sketchflow screens, ensure you paste after you have already added a "Sketchy" control to your screen and don't "Overwrite existing resource with copied resource" when a "Resource Key Conflict" occurs, "Discard the copied resource and use the existing resource" if the resources from your copied items already exist or leave as default and add them.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you've started by creating a new Sketchflow Application from Blend 3. Then from within Blend 3 in your Sketchflow project on the toolbar, click the chevron at the bottom of the list (the >>). From there expand Styles and select SketchStyles. From there you should see all the sketchy controls like BasicTextBox-Sketch and ListBox-Sketch. Those all have the sketchy look that you want.

It shows up at design time for me.

[image]
<sub>(source: [bryantlikes.com](http://files.bryantlikes.com/Images/sketchy.PNG))</sub>

Comment: That is what I've done. I started out with a new "Silverlight 3 SketchFlow Application", and all of my items end in "-Sketch". It turns out that in the SketchFlow Player, the font shows up properly. It doesn't at design-time, however.

Comment: It works at design time for me. What version of Blend are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.0.1927.0. I originally installed it from the demo, but then installed the whole Expression studio over it.